# c- Error Conlficting types within linked list struct

Tags: c

"I'm trying to implement a Linked List that will later make uses of a lexicographical sort function, but I keep getting an error concerning conflicting types in listnode.

I don't know what the cause of this issue is. Previously I had issues trying to malloc using sizeof and I found that the solution was declaring next as listnode* pointer. It solved that issue, but it still has conflicting types. When I try to compile I get this error message:

> ls.c:18:3: error: conflicting types for '**listnode**'
>   } listnode:
>   ls.c:12:14: note previous declaration of '**listnode**' was here
>   typedef node listnode;

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <dirent.h>
int strcmp(const char *str1, const char *str2);

//This chunk of code is dedicated to the formation and functions of Linked list
//which will be used to store and sort file names.
typedef struct node node;
typedef node listnode;
#define EMPTY NULL;

typedef struct listnode{
  struct listnode* next;
  char* string;
} listnode;

struct listnode* head;

//This function will print the entire list
void printlist(listnode* head){
 struct listnode* current = head;

 while(current != NULL){
    printf("%s \n", current->string);
    current = current->next;
 }
}

//This function creates a new node
listnode* newNode(char* str, listnode* node){
  listnode* new = (listnode*)malloc(sizeof(listnode*));
  if(new == NULL){
    printf("Error creating new listnode.\n");
    exit(0);
  }
  new->string = str;
  new->next = node;

  return new;
}

//This function will append a new node onto the list
listnode* list_append(listnode* head, char* str){
  if (head == NULL){
    listnode* new = newNode(str, head);
    head = new;
    return head;
  }
  else{
    listnode* current = head;
    while(current-> next != NULL){
      current = current->next;
    }

    listnode* new = newNode(str,NULL);
    current -> next = new;
  }
    return head;
}


//This function earses the list freeing up space
void list_free(listnode* head){
  listnode* current;
  listnode* temp;

  if(head != NULL){
    current = head->next;

    if(head !=NULL){
      current = head -> next;
      head ->next = NULL;
      while(current != NULL){
    temp = current -> next;
    free(current);
    current = temp;
      }
    }
  }
  free(head);
}



//This is the end of the linked list code

int main(int argc, char **argv){
  char *current_dir = NULL;
  DIR *direct_ptr = NULL;
  struct dirent *dir_ptr = NULL;
  unsigned int fileNum = 0;
  int c;
  listnode* head = NULL;

  current_dir = getenv("PWD");
  if(NULL == current_dir){
    printf("\n Error: Couldn't grab current directory.\n");
    return -1;
  }

  direct_ptr = opendir((const char*)current_dir);
  if(NULL == direct_ptr){
    printf("\n Error: couldn't open current directory\n");
    return -1;
  }

  if(argc == 1){
    for(fileNum=0; NULL != (dir_ptr = readdir(direct_ptr)); fileNum++){
      if(dir_ptr->d_name[0] != '.'){
        head = list_append(head, dir_ptr->d_name);
      }
    }
  }
  else{
    if(strcmp(argv[1], "-a") || strcmp(argv[1], "[-a]")){
      for(fileNum=0; NULL != (dir_ptr = readdir(direct_ptr)); fileNum++){
        head = list_append(head, dir_ptr->d_name);
      }
    }
    else{
      printf("\n Unrecognized argument in command line.\n");
      return -1;
    }
  }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: You have `typedef node listnode`, then a few lines later you have another `typedef` that defines `listnode`.

Answer (score 0):

You do in fact have conflicting definitions for `listnode`.  You first define the type here:

```
typedef struct node node;
typedef node listnode;
```

Then define it again here:

```
typedef struct listnode{
  struct listnode* next;
  char* string;
} listnode;
```

In one case it's an alias for `struct node` and in the other it's an alias for `struct listnode`.

Get rid of the first one as well as `typedef struct node node;`

Answer (score 0):

You have two definitions of `listnode`:

```
typedef node listnode;
```

and

```
typedef struct listnode{
  struct listnode* next;
  char* string;
} listnode;
```

The first one is unnecessary, and won't work, because it uses `node`, which is defined as

```
typedef struct node node;
```

but you never defined `struct node` anywhere.